# Symfony2 Custom Form Field Type HTML5 color

Tags: html, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to add the HTML5 color input type (only supported by Chrome at the moment) within a Symfony2 form.
I created a new color type which inherit from the text type :

```
<?php

namespace Marquis\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class ColorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'color';
    }
}

?>
```

and created a new service to use it :

```
marquis_website.form.type.color:
          class: Marquis\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\ColorType
          tags:
              - { name: form.type, alias: color }
```

However, when the form is display, the input tag looks like this :

```
<input type="text" id="entity_hex" name="entity[hex]" value="#4D89BF">
```

So it's not using the new HTML5 color input but the text input.

Is there a way to override the type so it would display type="color"?

I also checked the fields.html.twig and there is this line which should works fine:

```
{% set type = type|default('text') %}
```

If i change default('text') to default('color'), all the input type="text" are change to type="color".

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Stupid question but did you use 'color' on the second parameter in your add field method ?

Comment: Yes I do :)
->add('hex', 'color', array(
    'label' => 'Level color'
))

Comment: in case someone is looking for this answer now and using Symfony 3.4+, check the documentation, they've added a ColorType http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/color.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to define new theme block for your field

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block color_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = 'color' %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

[More about custom form fields](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field)

[More about custom form themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)